# Weird sound when modulating the pulse width on Arduino

Tags: arduino-nano, c++

I'm trying to generate a pulse width modulated sound using Arduino Nano.

But it generates the weird sound unlike my expectation.

**Here's my code:**

```
class Phasor
{
public:
    Phasor(const float frequency)
    :frequency(frequency)
    ,phase(1.0f)
    ,lastTimeMicros(0){};
    virtual ~Phasor(){};
    void setFrequency(const float frequency)
    {
        this->frequency = frequency;
    }
    float process()
    {
        const unsigned long currentTimeMicros = micros();
        if (phase == 1.0f) lastTimeMicros = currentTimeMicros;
        const unsigned long elapsedTimeMicros = currentTimeMicros - lastTimeMicros;
        const unsigned long cycleDurationMicros = static_cast<unsigned long>(1000.0f / frequency) * 1000;
        if (elapsedTimeMicros < cycleDurationMicros)
            phase = static_cast<float>(elapsedTimeMicros) / static_cast<float>(cycleDurationMicros);
        else
            phase = 1.0f;
        return phase;
    }
private:
    float frequency;
    float phase;
    unsigned long lastTimeMicros;
};

class PulseOsc
{
public:
    PulseOsc(const float frequency, const float pulseWidth)
    :phasor(frequency)
    ,pulseWidth(pulseWidth){};
    virtual ~PulseOsc(){};
    void setFrequency(const float frequency)
    {
        this->phasor.setFrequency(frequency);
    }
    void setPulseWidth(const float pulseWidth)
    {
        this->pulseWidth = pulseWidth;
    }
    float process()
    {
        const float phase = phasor.process();
        if (phase <= pulseWidth)
            return 1.0f;
        else
            return -1.0f;
    }
private:
    Phasor phasor;
    float pulseWidth;
};

Phasor *phasorLFO;
PulseOsc *pulseOsc;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
    phasorLFO = new Phasor(0.1f);
    pulseOsc = new PulseOsc(440.0f, 0.5f);
}

void loop()
{
    pulseOsc->setPulseWidth(phasorLFO->process());
    int outVal = LOW;
    if (pulseOsc->process() > 0.0f) outVal = HIGH;
    digitalWrite(9, outVal);
}
```

The resulting sound is very weird and glitchy.
It works fine when I fix the pulse width value. (without LFO)

What is wrong with my code?
How do I fix this? I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Probably the Nano isn't powerful enough to do all those floating point calculations in a timely manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues with this program. The first one has already been
pointed out by Majenko in a comment: you are doing too much floating
point calculations. The second has to do with the way your `Phasor`
manages the time.

If you take a look at the [Blink Without Delay](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay) Arduino tutorial, you
will see something along these lines:

```cpp
if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    toggle_the_LED();
}
```

In this code, `interval` is the *minimum* time between toggles. Whenever
the program gets a little bit late and `currentMillis - previousMillis`
is strictly larger than `interval`, this extra time is lost and the
program will be late for all the subsequent LED toggles. If instead of
the minimum you are interested in the *average* time between toggles,
then you should write:

```cpp
if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    previousMillis += interval;  // <- advance by exactly one period
    toggle_the_LED();
}
```

Now, `previousMillis` is no more the time when the last toggle was
*performed*, it is the time when the last toggle was *scheduled*. With
this version you can still have some jitter, but at least the average
frequency should be right. If the program is so busy that it can get
late by a full period, then it would be better to replace the `if` by a
`while`, in order to catch up all the missed periods.

Your `Phasor::process()` method is a little bit more involved than the
tutorial above, yet the line

```cpp
if (phase == 1.0f) lastTimeMicros = currentTimeMicros;
```

is going to get you out of schedule for exactly the same reason.

That being said, here is my take at your phasor idea, *completely
untested*:

```cpp
class Phasor()
{
public:
    Phasor(float frequency_Hz)
    {
        period = round(1e6 / frequency_Hz);
        frequency = 0x10000 / period;
    }
    uint16_t process()
    {
        uint16_t now = micros();
        while (now - last_time >= period)
            last_time += period;
        return (now - last_time) * frequency;
    }
private:
    uint16_t period;     // unit = 1 us
    uint16_t frequency;  // unit = 1/(2^16 us) ~ 15.3 Hz
    uint16_t last_time = 0;
};
```

I changed a few things from your implementation:

- removed the `setFrequency()` method because [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)
- no floating point except in the constructor, for performance reasons
- only 16-bit arithmetics, for the same reason
- no division in `process()`, because division is expensive
- the phase is not stored, because there is no use to storing it
- the phase is an integer in units of 2<sup>−16</sup> periods

Note that the unit chosen for the phase is the most natural one when
dealing with 16-bit arithmetics. Note also that storing microseconds in
16-bit variables only works for frequencies higher than 15.3 Hz. A
very low frequency phasor (your “LFO” for instance) would need 32-bit
arithmetics.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are using the system clock `micros()` to  calculate `elapsedTimeMicros`, so probably the time spent on the process of calculation and sending signal to the pin may affect it, which may lead to inconsistent duty cycle.